# Windows 2016 DNS server returns SERVFAIL for non-existing domain

Tags: domain-name-system, srvfail

I have two DNS resolvers in /etc/resolv.conf file. The top one is Windows DNS server, and the bottom one is my wi-fi router. Please see below.
  nameserver 192.168.1.126
  nameserver 192.168.1.1

In Windows DNS server, the sole "Forward Lookup Zone" is biman.net

When I query for host in the zone (biman.net) the Windows DNS server works fine-- either it returns the IP or NXDOMAIN. But when I query for anything for non-existing zone it returns SERVFAIL. But the wifi router returns NXDOMAIN even when zone name is bogus.

How can I get NXDOMAIN response from Windows DNS server when zone does not exist?

Below are the queries and the responses.

root@VDIkali:~# nslookup -q=A kali2.biman.net
Server:     192.168.1.126
Address:    192.168.1.126#53

Name:   kali2.biman.net
Address: 192.168.1.122

root@VDIkali:~# nslookup -q=A NOHOST.biman.net
Server:     192.168.1.126
Address:    192.168.1.126#53

** server can't find NOHOST.biman.net: NXDOMAIN

root@VDIkali:~# nslookup -q=A kali2.NONEXTING.net
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.1.126, trying next server
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find kali2.NONEXTING.net: NXDOMAIN

Comment: have either. net or notexisting.net as domain running? can you upload a screen shot.?

Comment: NONEXiSTING.net domain does not exist. biman.net domain exists. Kali2 host exists in biman.net domain

Comment: I got another question related to DNS again.   was analysing my DNS traffic using tcpdump (not verbose mode) in a AIX client. I found that a lot of repeat of transaction IDs over matter of hours, and even for different query (see the evidence below. Is it expected?   19:30:06.039765 IP 172.18.140.80.43852 > 172.28.3.40.53: 56554+ AAAA? 172.18.140.80.sg.uobnet.com. (45)
19:30:06.040741 IP 172.28.3.40.53 > 172.18.140.80.43852: 56554 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (110)
19:30:06.644668 IP 172.18.140.80.43873 > 172.28.3.40.53: 56554+ AAAA? DMPCUSG01. (27)
19:30:06.645465 IP 172.28.3.40.53 >

Comment: And one more evidence where transaction ID repeats over an hour : 19:20:00.768582 IP 172.18.140.80.43432 > 172.28.3.40.53: 62969+ AAAA? DMPCUSG01. (27)
19:20:00.769278 IP 172.28.3.40.53 > 172.18.140.80.43432: 62969 ServFail 0/0/0 (27)
19:20:00.769344 IP 172.18.140.80.43433 > 172.18.3.40.53: 62969+ AAAA? DMPCUSG01. (27)
19:20:00.769775 IP 172.18.3.40.53 > 172.18.140.80.43433: 62969 ServFail 0/0/0 (27)
20:30:01.433471 IP 172.18.140.80.46031 > 172.28.3.40.53: 62969+ AAAA? DMPCUSG01. (27)

Comment: if your intention is to resolve names of biman.net as well as external domain names, the proper setup is to have forwarder configured on your Windows DNS, use it as your only resolver instead of having 2 resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

You get `SERVFAIL` for non-existing names, if the DNS server is configured to *be* able to resolve the name, but it actually *cannot* do it. Two example scenarios:

1. **Your Windows DNS server is online:** Make sure that the server can reach its root DNS servers, so they can serve `NXDOMAIN` for non-existing names. Otherwise your server would serve `SERVFAIL` for all names it does not serve itself.
2. **Your Windows DNS server is air-gapped:** Make sure to remove all root servers, as it won't reach them anyway. Add your own (probably empty) root DNS zone named `.` (yes, just the *dot*). Then your Windows DNS server will return `NXDOMAIN` for all names it does not know.